# jquery how to write proper json object in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

what is the best way to write json object in c#? I have a piece of code which is supposed to get data from DB and write json object but I haven't had my mind clear about this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string get_specialities(string ProfessionalID)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Connection String2");
    DbCommand dbCommand;
    dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("select_Professionals_Speciality");
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "prof_id", DbType.Int16, Convert.ToInt16(ProfessionalID));
    IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
    //[{ id: 3, name: "test3" }]
    string return_str="[";
    int i = 0;
    while (dr.Read()) {
        if (i > 0)
            return_str += ",";
        return_str += "{id:" + dr["SpecialtyID"].ToString().Trim() + ",name:" + dr["SpecialtyName"].ToString().Trim() + "}";
        i++;
    }
    return_str += "]";
    return return_str;
}
```

this returns the object below, which is in wrong format

```
{"d":"[{id:67,name:Kardiyoloji}]"}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `NewtonSoft.JSON` is what you looking for. And little sugestion use `StringBuilder` when you creating string it's make a different in performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using [JavaScriptSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
Person p = new Person();

while (dr.Read()) {
    p = new Person();
    p.id = dr["SpecialtyID"].ToString().Trim();
    p.name = dr["SpecialtyName"].ToString().Trim();
    people.Add(p);
}

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string return_str = serializer.Serialize(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

About the code you provided, the right json should be:

```
{"d":[{"id":67,"name":"Kardiyoloji"}]}
```

You can check with jsonlint:
http://jsonlint.com/

Use a serializer.
I suggest NewtonSoft.
You can find a lot of samples around, otherwise ask for a snippet of code here

Answer (score 0):

directly converting to string is not a good idea generally... you should use serialize such as jobs... but you can try like this

```
{"d":'[{"id":67,"name":"Kardiyoloji"}]'}
```

are you gonna deserialize value of d again ?

Comment: how can I return it as json object rather than string

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you don't know how to write special char in your string which is `"` double quota in your case?

replace:
`"{id:" + dr["SpecialtyID"].ToString().Trim() + ",name:" + dr["SpecialtyName"].ToString().Trim() + "}";`

for

`"{\"id\":" + dr["SpecialtyID"].ToString().Trim() + "\",\"name\":\"" + dr["SpecialtyName"].ToString().Trim() + "\"}";`

will do what you need.
But better way is using a `NewtonSoft` serializer for JSON handling.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid manually building the JSON string.

Rather, map the db data into the corresponding object (entity?), and then serialize it into JSON.

You can use the [Javascript Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). I also use the [JayRock library](http://jayrock.berlios.de/).